# When does YouTube update their views for channels?

Tags: youtube

After 4 days my videos are gaining views. However, the total views on my channel has stayed the same. When does YouTube update the views for the channel? Is it every week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> View count information for your video in the trailer location may be
>   different than what you see on the watch page or in YouTube Analytics
>   due to **differences in timing of data updates** in each location. [source](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2976827)

.

> We want to make sure that all views are validated so during this
>   process the views update less frequently and **might occasionally freeze
>   above 300 views to assure quality view count**. This is the normal
>   operation in YouTube videos. [source](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2991876)

.

> **We've noticed a lot of you reporting issues with your view counts not
>   updating correctly** over the past couple days. I wanted to let you all
>   know that we're currently investigating this issue and hope to have it
>   resolved soon.
>
> In the meantime, you can check your current and accurate viewcount by
>   going to your Analytics page and checking the stats for the video you
>   want.
>
> If you haven't tried it before, you can access Analytics by following
>   these steps:
>
> 1) Click on your username in the top right
>
> 2) Click on Video Manager
>
> 3) Click on Analytics at the top of the page
>
> **Views on Analytics are accurate and should display the most up-to-date
>   snapshot of a video's views.**
>
> **Typically, however, there are times when you might notice your view
>   counts slowing or temporarily freezing.**
>
> If you're still not seeing what look like accurate and current counts
>   on Analytics, **be sure to try Insight as well.** You can find it at
>   http:// www.youtube.com/my_videos_insight. [source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/j2wSpyE0p4w%5B1-25-false%5D)

.

> **Analytics views data is updated once a day, which means that the
>   numbers displayed in these reports may differ from** the public values
>   displayed on the video page, **channel page,** Video Manager, or other
>   sources.
>
> If your public video viewcount is frozen at 301+, and the value is
>   different than the count displayed in YouTube Analytics, **this may be
>   the result of our viewcount validation process.** [source](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714329)

**Finally the update time of the views for the channel is not announced officially yet so it is unknown.**

Answer (score 3):

View counts should be updated every few hours but it can go up to one week or more. YouTube justifies this varying count update delay by saying they are trying to ensure that the count is accurate (i.e. not artificially boosted):

[An Update On Our View Counts - YouTube Official Blog](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2009/03/update-on-our-view-counts.html)

> Video view counts reflect the YouTube community's interests and the
>   grassroots popularity of videos. We periodically make changes that
>   allow us to display consistent view counts and accurately reflect a
>   "real" view based on video consumption, video streaming and spam
>   filtering. Unfortunately, a few people still try to artificially
>   manipulate their video's view counts. Some people game third-party
>   view counts as well. That can make things unfair for everyone.
>
> Recently, we found spamming issues associated with the view counts on
>   a small number of videos. The inflated view count number on these
>   videos will be frozen until actual views catch up to the published,
>   artificial, view count. Also, a few people have commented that their
>   view counts are updating more slowly. **Occasionally the speed with
>   which views update changes -- sometimes it’s faster and sometimes it’s
>   slower.** But we are always working to make sure that the final view
>   count numbers are an accurate reflection of the community's interest.
>
> Michelle Schlachta
>
> Community Manager, The YouTube Team

[Why do YouTube videos get stuck at 301 views?](http://www.dailydot.com/news/youtube-videos-301-views-bug/)

> “We get asked about it all the time,”  Ted Hamilton, a product manager for YouTube analytics said. “I wouldn’t say that it
>   causes angst, but I would certainly classify it as an annoyance.”
>
> **After a video reaches a certain number of views, Hamilton explained,
>   YouTube tells the database to freeze the view count until YouTube can
>   manually verify the correct count to protect against botting
>   attempts—i.e. using automated computer processes to artificially
>   inflate the number of views.** YouTube view counts are initially tracked
>   by servers near the end user. By looking at reports from these
>   individual servers, YouTube engineers can detect suspicious patterns
>   in the data.
>
> “At some point the decision was made that we need to draw a line
>   between what is innocuous and the database can handle and all of a
>   sudden serious business,” he said. “The proportion was calculated to
>   be at about 300.”
>
> So why 301? Blame it on one YouTube programmer’s errant
>   less-than-or-equal-to sign. The code tells the database to keep
>   counting views up to and including the time when the count is equal to
>   300, allowing one final view to get counted before it freezes.
>
> “Whoever wrote this code probably did not realize the magnitude of
>   what they were doing,” said Hamilton. “It is now one of the
>   idiosyncrasies of YouTube.”

Since the view locking is an automated computer processes, YouTube has to use some heuristics to decide whether lock, and they very likely compare the popularity of your account with the slope of the number of views for the video, amongst other things.

You might want to give a try to the [frozen view count Google help page](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2991876?hl=en).

Comment: So the view count could take weeks to fix itself?

Comment: Yes it's a plague, there have been thousands of complaints over Internet, e.g. https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/youtube/ozp7DWQvcI8/-7bzSXMni2UJ . As far as I know the best you can do is to  try the frozen view count Google help page. I'd be curious to know what YouTube engineers do when detecting suspicious patterns in the data that cannot be automated.